# how can i read the openGL code which is converted from WebGL or Unity 3d

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, gpu, webgl, unity-game-engine

As it is known that WebGL and Unity3D are converted to OpenGL which in return can be read by GPU..

My question is this,

Is there any tool or program that can read this OpenGL code.

Comment: As main OpenGL IS NOT read by GPU, but it's library that performs operations on GPU. WebGL is almost same, but it's wrapper for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To see the calls made to OpenGL, while rendering WebGL or Unity3D content, see [What is the best way to debug OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518063/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-opengl)