# visual tools for debugging opengl programs

Tags: opengl

Is there any library which provides functions for debugging programs using opengl?

I mean functions which provide visual help, like drawing the xy plane, or a sphere at the origin, or show a scene in wireframe mode.

Comment: Simple tasks can be made by yourself, e.g. zero plane, spheres, axis dummy. For more complex and versatile debugging refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518063/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-opengl

Answer (score 0):

To draw in wireframe mode you only have to use:

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
```